# Prompt for text, rename file or folder appending that text, and copy to fixed folder - Windows environment

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file

This is what I am after.

1. File or folder is dragged and dropped on the application shortcut
2. User is prompted for an entry
3. The dropped file or folder is renamed, with the text returned from the prompt as a file prefix, followed by a separator character (hyphen, underscore, space - any of those)
4. Renamed file or folder is copied to a specific destination folder, which is always the same folder

If that is impossible, this is another option:

1. Application is launched (no drag and drop)
2. User is prompted to browse to file or folder to select it
3. User is then prompted for text entry
   (note: steps 2 and 3 can be reversed if it makes things easier)
4. File or folder selected in step 2 is renamed with the text returned from 3 as a prefix, followed by a separator character
5. Renamed file or folder is copied to a specific destination folder, which is always the same folder

The destination folder is a hot folder. So best to do the renaming before the copy.

I have done this in Mac environment using AppleScript. I am not sure about how to approach in Windows. BAT file? Javascript? At this point all I have done is write a javascript which prompts for text and returns text string as an alert, with returned text of prompt in the string in a Mac environment:

```js
var app = Application("Finder")
app.includeStandardAdditions = true


var response = app.displayDialog("ENTER JOB NO",{
defaultAnswer: "",
buttons: ["Cancel","Continue"],
defaultButton: "Continue"
})
app.displayDialog("Hello! Your job number is " + (response.textReturned))
```

Different from Windows, and I am not as proficient in Windows, bat files, or javascript either. Also I'm not sure if javascript is the best approach for what I want.

Comment: Trying to get started, and my knowledge is limited. Wrote a simple bat file:

@echo off
set /p "jobno=Enter Job No: "

Dropped file brings up the prompt. Now to rename the dropped file and copy it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a .bat:

```
@echo off
echo The file you dropped is: %1
set /p "jobno=Enter Job No: "
```

Dropped file or folder is identified as a path, and then it prompts for entry.

Not much of a start, but something. One problem I see is extracting the file name from the path. The job number would need to be inserted after the final "/"

Another possibility:

1. File or folder is dropped on bat
2. User is prompted for job number
3. New folder created on desktop, with the job number being the name of the folder
4. Original dropped file or folder is moved into this new folder
5. The job number folder containing the original drop is then copied to the final destination

This would work and I get around renaming.

Is Powershell a better option for this, instead of a batch file? Sorry for my lack of knowledge here.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another bat

```
@echo off
echo The file you dropped is: %1
set /p "jobno=Enter Job No: "
set varfile=%1
xcopy %varfile% "C:\Users\me\Desktop\%jobno%\"/s
```

This seems to work. Strange result if the dropped is a folder. It actually extracts all contents from the original folder and copies them to the new folder named with the job number.

The /s ensures that subfolders are also copied, if they exist.

I am still wondering if Powershell might be a better solution. I get the impression that it is far superior to bat files. Maybe the bat files are outdated, like AppleScript on a Mac.